# Please add gallery thumbnails to this site's search results

Tags: support, feature-request, meta, stackapps

I would like to link to [a list of all my stuff](https://stackapps.com/search?q=%5Bscript%5D+user%3A25350), but I'd like it to display with [thumbnails and excerpts](https://stackapps.com/questions/2003/guidelines-on-app-and-library-thumbnails) (like it does on [tag searches](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script)).

Is this possible? It seems like a reasonable use case, but for some reason if the search terms include anything but a tag, the result list isn't in gallery form.

Comment: Not a big need for this.  Just make a GitHub page.  As a bonus, it'll help you get the *Announcer/Booster/Publicist* badges.

Comment: I guess; I'll do that... but it seems like it's a waste of the nice fancy thumbnail and description feature that's already built-in, you know? And in any case, it seems off that a tag search shows thumbnails, but add a `user:` constraint, and it doesn't any more.

Comment: I admit, it would be nice to have.  But there's 215 other fixes I personally want more. ;)

Comment: @BrockAdams 215 +/- [31000](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/680687/fr-bug-without-status-tags-network-wide), heh.