# api 2.0 - any plans to bring SE sites closer together?

Tags: discussion, api-v2

I've been re-reading [api 2.0 roadmap](https://stackapps.com/questions/1999/announcing-api-version-1-1) and thinking what might be useful to have there.

I don't care much about authentification, and even less about write access. But what would really reduce amount of requests I make drastically is ability to aggregate information from different SE sites.

E.g., now we have to fetch user's posts from every single site separately with `/questions/{id}`, while ideally there would also be common `/questions/{association-id}` endpoint on `stackauth`.

Amount of SE sites grow, many users actively participate on several sites and it's hard to keep track of user's activity otherwise.

Are there any technical problems with this concept, like sites using separate physical servers? Is there any chance we might move towards it? This doesn't seem to be easy, but it would also reduce load on SE servers significantly.

Thank you

Comment: +1 (+100 if I could). Sadly StackAuth 1.1 has gone in the opposite direction; increasing the amount of requests you need to do.