# Is there an authentication component to the API?

Tags: support, authentication

Is there an authentication component with the API?  Same as logging in with Facebook or Google etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none in version 1.1 of the API: all the information in the API is public.

This is [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) for version 2, however. [Read more.](https://stackapps.com/questions/1999/announcing-api-version-1-1)

Comment: I'd upvote but I am not allows .... sigh